# HTML Form Action: How to fetch text field & create a URL for Action (Method: POST)

Tags: html, forms

I have a form like:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.2-myWebSiteUri.com/file1.php" id="login">
<input type="text" name="TEXTBOX1"></input>
<input type="text" name="TEXTBOX2"></input>
<button type="submit" class="button" title="login" name="send" id="send2">Login</button></form>
```

I would like to perform custom "action=" in FORM using POST (method) however I am not getting how to perform it. Form action should be like, for example:

```
<form action="http://www.2-myWebSiteUri.com/TEXTBOX1/file1.php" method="post" id="login">
```

BUT form should collect the text value (TEXTBOX1) from the TEXTBOX1 which user will enter and same should be used as a input value in action URL as given above in the place of TEXTBOX1. Suppose in TEXTBOX1, I have written input value as "pasta" & submitted via button, then action url should be like:

```
<form action="http://www.2-myWebSiteUri.com/pasta/file1.php" method="post" id="login">
```

or if input value is noodles then action url should be like

```
<form action="http://www.2-myWebSiteUri.com/noodles/file1.php" method="post" id="login">
```

upon submission.

I've small authentication based scripts in different directories of domain 
`www.2-myWebSiteUri.com` and I am trying to create a single form so that all can be logged in using a single form. User will just enter directory name "such as pasta and noodles as given in above example". This form will be hosted on another domain `www.1-myWebSiteUri.com` and when user wants to make login any of the scripts then he will open: 
`www.1-myWebSiteUri.com/login.php` and this is the same login form for which I want to have custom actions.

Actually, I am trying to use directories as a category of games which host few online games. Categories will not be fixed and it will be added randomly, so i want to keep TEXTBOX instead of a Drop Down. We may halt few features in the game for different users. You can take this as a different directories with different games which can be accessed only via authentication. I just want to post all the credentials using a single form instead of 100 forms for each game and it will be very tough to share all these login links with users.

I have tested couple of codes including javascripts however none of them are working. I will be more then happy if any of you assist me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

No, that will not work.

You need a middle-ware script. Your description is lacking detail but this may help.

**Change action destination to middle.php**

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.2-myWebSiteUri.com/middle.php" id="login">
<input type="text" name="TEXTBOX1"></input>
<input type="text" name="TEXTBOX2"></input>
<button type="submit" class="button" title="login" name="send" id="send2">Login</button></form>
```

**middle.php**
Value of TEXTBOX1 is inserted into url as $txt1.

```
<?php

$txt1 = trim($_POST['TEXTBOX1']);
$txt2 = trim($_POST['TEXTBOX2']);
include("http://www.2-myWebSiteUri.com/$txt1/file1.php");

?>
```

Depending on values of TEXTBOX1 you may need to add urlencode:

```
$txt1 = urlencode(trim($_POST['TEXTBOX1']));
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Do i have to host this middle.php on www.2-myWebSiteUri.com right? but how credentials will get posted to the file1.php through middle.php because TEXTBOX2 may be used as a password field or may be a new text box will be added and used as a password.

Comment: Does not really matter.  It is best to keep it in the same domain as the form.

Comment: "how credentials will get posted ", I do not know because I have no idea what you are doing or why you want to do this.  You will have to edit you question and add more details.

Comment: If i place in the same domain, will it make the things easy to work?. Actually at present I am testing the code on different hostings. As you said, I will try to move everything on single domain. I have added a paragraph in description at last.

Comment: hi @Misunderstood , thanks for your answer. it is worked for me. actually i am sacing some problem with this action.php page in my magento website. now i kept the url of my desired page at <form method="post" action="my url.....">. it worked for me. Thank you.